# What does this code really do?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am testing iThemes security plugin for Wordpress.
It adds the following code:

```
        # Rules to help reduce spam
        location /wp-comments-post.php {
            valid_referers jetpack.wordpress.com/jetpack-comment/ *.mysite.com;
            set $rule_0 0;
            if ($request_method ~ "POST"){ set $rule_0 1$rule_0; }
            if ($invalid_referer) { set $rule_0 2$rule_0; }
            if ($http_user_agent ~ "^$"){ set $rule_0 3$rule_0; }
            if ($rule_0 = "3210") { return 403; }
        }
```

The author describes it as "This option will cut down on comment spam by denying comments from bots with no referrer or without a user-agent identified."

it looks like to me that ALL the conditions must be met.

What does this code really do? What does `$rule_0 = "3210"` mean?

Comment: Looks like it set `$rule_0` to 0 and then prepend "1" to it if the first test is true, and then prepend "2" to the string built so far if the second test is true and finally prepend "3" if the third test is true. So if all tests are true, `$rule_0` ends up with the value "3210". Indeed, it looks that ALL the conditions must be met to return 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE:* Apparently this is not `php` - this is merely an `nginx` config file, as is noted in the comments below.

I don't know `php` but this looks pretty straight forward. This is how I think it works:

```
valid_referers jetpack.wordpress.com/jetpack-comment/ *.mysite.com;
        set $rule_0 0;
```

That just sets up default ok values. Notice here that we're defining `$rule0_0` to have a value of `0`.

```
 if ($request_method ~ "POST"){ set $rule_0 1$rule_0; }
```

If the http request is `BITWISE NOT` the word `POST,` set `$rule_0` to equal `10`.

It continues in that pattern, adding 2 and 3 to the value of `$rule_0 if` there is an invalid `referrer` or an invalid `user_agent.`

```
if ($rule_0 = "3210") { return 403; }
```

Here `if` there has been a combination of invalid `$request_method, $http_user_agent` and `referrer` then `$rule_0` will equal `3210` and the php server will return a `403: FORBIDDEN.`

Comment: This is not PHP, it is nginx configuration file ;)

Comment: It looks a like php to me... Can its config interpret php?

Comment: No it cannot. It only looks similar.